# Add back USB boot option in BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a [samsung](http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/notebook/essential/NP350V5C-S08IN) notebook. It came with Windows 8 and UEFI. I was able to do dual boot with Ubuntu 13.04 using USB installation. I had some issues with the boot, so I ran boot-repair and everything worked fine. However, I want to reinstall my Ubuntu since I have some problems with the graphical drivers. Then I looked at the boot options and I don't have the USB boot entry anymore. I tried to create a new boot entry using efibootmgr, but that didn't work, it looks like efibootmgr is not able to add entries in Ubuntu 13.04. When I run efibootmgr, it show this:

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0001,0005,0006,0007,0000,0002,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002  UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0003  UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0004* ubuntu
Boot0005* ubuntu
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0007* ubuntu
```

I tried to load the default options, but it didn't change the boot list. I know I can re-install Ubuntu in different ways, but I would love to have my boot list with the USB option again.

Just clarifying that's NOT a BIOS issue. This was working before installing Ubuntu. I was able to use USB stick to install Ubuntu. This is happening with other people as well. Please look at the problem more further before put on hold

Comment: It is not a BIOS issue, since the BIOS was working before install ubuntu. Please do not put this on hold. This is a ubuntu issue. I have said that before, this has happened after the boot repair.

Comment: You can look at similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425672/remove-ubuntu-from-boot-menu-in-bios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a BIOS, so you're technically correct that it's not a BIOS issue; but it ***is*** a firmware (EFI, in your case) issue, not a Linux issue. That said, your installation of Linux has probably disrupted the list of boot options that the EFI maintains in NVRAM. It's possible that you'll be able to restore the USB option by fiddling with your firmware's settings, but it's impossible for me to say what you might need to adjust because EFIs vary so much in the options they present and how you use them. Note also that it may be necessary to have a bootable USB flash drive inserted into the computer when you enter the firmware setup utility for it to do the right thing. Note also that the option in question might be something related to USB initialization or a "fast boot" setting. (Some computers do limited or no initialization of USB at boot time in order to shave an extra couple seconds off the boot time.)

If you can't find any suitable options, you might try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) It scans all the boot devices it can find, so if the computer initializes the USB devices, rEFInd *should* detect a bootable USB device. (Note that by default, rEFInd will detect only EFI-bootable devices, though; if you want rEFInd to detect a BIOS-mode boot disk, you must uncomment and adjust the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf`.) If you install the rEFInd Debian package, be aware that it will take over as the default/primary boot loader.

Comment: What you recommended worked fine. However, I don't know how and why the firmware changed the fast bios options to enable again. It was disabled before I install Ubuntu, otherwise the USB wouldn't boot right? It is solved though. Thanks for your help